# Coordinate Rotation in PHP

Tags: php, rotation, trigonometry

(This question is specific to PHP, I know this is discussed in other languages, but I'm having trouble with implementing it in PHP.)

I'm attempting to rotate the x & y coordinates of a feature which is to be placed on a rotated image.

`$x` & `$y` are the original x,y coordinates of the block before the image was rotated.

`$width2` & `$height2` are the center of rotation (which is the center of the image).

`$sin` & `$cos` are the sine & cosine, which are obtained with `sin($radians)` and 
`cos($radians)` on the degree of rotation the (background) image was rotated by (in radians)

```
function RotatePoints($x,$y,$width2,$height2,$sin,$cos)
    {
    // translate point back to origin:
    $x -= $width2;
    $y -= $height2;

    // rotate point
    $x = $x * $cos - $y * $sin;
    $y = $x * $sin + $y * $cos;

    // translate point back:
    $x += $width2;
    $y += $height2;

    return array($x,$y);
    }
```

Supposedly this function should give me the new coordinates of the block, with the rotation taken into account. But the positioning is quite far off.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If i'ts been a while since you did trigonometry, allow me to save you from the high-school rabbit whole I just crawled up from. _Radians_ means taking an angle (like 45°) and multiplying it with pi / 180. `$radians = $angle * (pi()/180);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use other variables when you compute the rotation, in your code:

```
$x = $x * $cos - $y * $sin;
$y = $x * $sin + $y * $cos;
```

$x is modified by the first equation, then you're using wrong value of $x in the second.

Change to:

```
$temp_x = $x * $cos - $y * $sin;
$temp_y = $x * $sin + $y * $cos;
```

Comment: Wow! That was a school-boy mistake! *Embarrassed* I'll change it and let you know if that fixes the problem. Thanks.