# PHP - How to get the coordinates of the point after rotation?

Tags: php, rotation, coordinates, imagick

I want the eyes in the image to be horizontal

```
$rightEyeY = 446;
$rightEyeX = 625;
$leftEyeY = 433;
$leftEyeX = 733;

// Get middle point of two eyes
$y = $rightEyeY - $leftEyeY;
$x = $rightEyeX - $leftEyeX;

$angle = rad2deg(atan2($y, $x)) - 180; // -6.8 degrees

$manager = new ImageManager(['driver' => 'imagick']);
$image = $manager->make('image.jpg')->rotate($angle);
$a = $angle * pi() / 180.0;
$cosa = cos($a);
$sina = sin($a);
$x = $x * $cosa - $y * $sina; // This one calculates x of the middle point not each eye.
$y = $x * $sina + $y * $cosa; // This one calculates y of the middle point not each eye.
```

How can I get the coordinates of each eye after rotation?

I want those variables at the top

```
FROM:
```

rightEyeY = 446

rightEyeX = 625

leftEyeY = 433

leftEyeX = 733

```
TO:
```

rightEyeY = 432

rightEyeX = 640

leftEyeY = 432

leftEyeX = 749

Comment: Middle point would be division by two of `$rightEyeY - $leftEyeY;`

Comment: `How can I get the coordinates of each eye after rotation?` - Why don't you rotate each eye?

Comment: Also as pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742237/coordinate-rotation-in-php, you are calculating `$x` and `$y` at the same time as using them in a calculation.

Comment: @NigelRen He is subtracting and then adding. But I'm doing that. I just calculate and put it in the variable. Even if I change the variable name, it won't affect the result.

Comment: In the first calc - `$x = $x * $cosa - $y * $sina;`, you change the value of `$x`, surely this would affect the next result `$y = $x * $sina + $y * $cosa;`, which is relying on the original x co-ord.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I want to rotate the image. Is it possible to rotate by two coordinates?

Comment: @NigelRen yes you are right, but surprisingly the result is not the one that I want. I want the coordinates of each eye separately. But the `$x` and `$y` don't have the value I said in the question.

Comment: @kodfire I am not a math expert, but if you would have a vector from midpoint of the image to each eye, and then do the rotation for both, the results of each may be the new coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried something, but got other coordinates. It looks right for me. The trick is the rotation translating to the center. I think the difference comes from the angle of -6.83 to be wrong (distance of eyes in your OP code).

> If you do not translate, the rotation will be done at (0,0) the origin of the coordinate system which is then top left corner in image space, but you want the center.

```php
$angle = deg2rad(-6.83);
list($leftX,  $leftY)  = $rotateEye($leftEyeX, $leftEyeY, $angle);
list($rightX, $rightY) = $rotateEye($rightEyeX, $rightEyeY, $angle);
```

and gives me

```
L: (734.56131177907, 734.56131177907)
R: (628.87375746869, 418.91568508316)
```

But the image looks like that, blue left, red right. The bottom pair is the origin, the top one rotated by -6.83 degree.

[image]

2D rotation matrix and translation code

```php
$rotateEye = function ($x, $y, $angle) use ($centerX, $centerY): array {
    $tx = $x - $centerX;
    $ty = $y - $centerY;
    $rx = cos($angle) * $tx - sin($angle) * $ty;
    $ry = sin($angle) * $tx + cos($angle) * $ty;
    return [$rx + $centerX, $ry + $centerY];
};
```

Here a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/8Mzu1Sx1) of the complete code.

Comment: It seems after rotating, its width and height get bigger. because the rotation doesn't go under the back but it extends the width and height. Is it possible to prevent this extension in images during rotation?

Comment: As stated, it depends on the rotation center. Imagine a projected circle for each eye and it looks correct for me. You did not provide the original image size, so I assumed 800x800.

Comment: The sizes are various in different images. But this one was 1500x1125. In Photoshop when I rotate the image it hides under the back. But in Imagick, it makes the workspace bigger. I couldn't find any method to set the center point.

Comment: Photoshop always rotates around the center and does a clipping, so the image won't grow. When using imagick you need to clip by yourself. Look for [chop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.chopimage.php) and [crop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.cropimage.php).

Comment: Having complete other dimensions will of course result in different values, because the rotation center is different. I am quite sure, my answer is correct, with the tests I did. The image size must be the same after rotation to match the correct coordinates or you need to add the new offsets. (newSizeX-oldSizeX)/2 and same for Y.

Comment: By `(newSizeX-oldSizeX)/2` you mean `$image->width() - $imageBeforeRotation->width() / 2` ?

Comment: Yes, but don't miss the parenthesis for order! Same for height. Or crop the image appropriately. `2 + 3 / 2` !== `(2 + 3) / 2`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229602/discussion-between-kodfire-and-markus-zeller).

Comment: `$image->rotate($angle); $x = ($image->width() - $imageWidth) / 2;
$y = ($image->height() - $imageHeight) / 2;

$centerX = $image->width() / 2;
$centerY = $image->height() / 2;
$rotateEye = function
.
.
.
list($leftX, $leftY) = $rotateEye($leftEyeX, $leftEyeY, $angle);
list($rightX, $rightY) = $rotateEye($rightEyeX, $rightEyeY, $angle);

echo $leftX; // 632.25251473382
echo $leftY; // 506.70067768126
echo $rightX; // 549.07436361973
echo $rightY; // 576.80342496868` None of them the ones expected.

Comment: ImageRotate() expects angle in deg, $rotateEye() exepects angle in rad. Also you forgot to add the offsets. `$leftX += $x` and `$leftY += $y`. Please have a CLOSER look to my code and comments.

Comment: After rotating, I used `$angle = deg2rad($angle)` to convert it from degree to radian. I added `$leftX += $x` and `$leftY += $y` but the result is not correct yet. THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR TIME.      `764.96433693639
519.19682518247
659.29194368963
545.01049027485`

Comment: When I take my code and change `$width = 1500; $height = 1125` and do a rotation by -6.83 deg, my result is: (718, 718) and (612, 462).

Comment: I don't know why the points are not the ones that I want. I edited the question. Could you please take a look? @MarkusZeller

Comment: Please never change a question after an answer is placed. Please revert and create a new question. Also the content is now totally different. As you stated you are rotating in the wrong direction!